# Use JpaTemplate in java with transactions handled?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have started looking at the possibility of using JpaTemplate to remove some boiler plate code in some of my applications.

I have something like this right now:

```
public class SomeDaoClass {

    public SomeDaoClass( boolean handleTransactionsLocally ) {
            _handleTransactionsLocally = handleTransactionsLocally;
    }

    private void persist( final Object object ) throws MyCustomException {
        try {
            if ( _handleTransactionsLocally ) {
                EntityTransaction transaction = getEntityManager().getTransaction();

                transaction.begin();
                getEntityManager().persist( object );
                transaction.commit();
            }
            else {
                getEntityManager().persist( object );
                getEntityManager().flush();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception exception ) {
            throw new MyCustomException( exception );
        }
    }
}
```

When ran from a unit test, I override the `getEntityManager()` and provide true to the contructor. When I deploy this to the server, I simply return the injected entity manager from the container.

However, it seems like I should be able to do something like this instead:

```
        _jpaTemplate = new JpaTemplate( getEntityManager() );
        _jpaTemplate.persist( object );
```

How can I specify in the java code how the `jpaTemplate` should handle transactions? I've tried annotating the method with `@Transactional` but this doesn't seem to work. Do I need to set a property on the `_jpaTemplate`? Is this even possible?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding `@Transactional`, you need to specify `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your `applicationContext.xml`, and also have a bean called `transactionManager`, that (in your case) is of type `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`

As a sidenote - it is usually not a good idea to make DAOs transactional. You'd better have your service layer transactional instead.

Comment: But is there any way to do this without a applicationContext.xml? That's what I'm driving for here.

Comment: you have applicationContext.xml. And you can't have declarative transactions without adding stuff to it.

Comment: I don't have an applicationContext.xml - I'm trying to use JpaTemplate in the same way as the JdbcTemplate classes if that makes any sense.

Comment: If you ate using spring, you have the xml file. If not using spring you cannot get iits transactipn support

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bozho's answer, you actually don't need to use `JpaTemplate` in order to get declarative transactions.

The typical approach to use JPA with declarative transactions in Spring is to use a shared `EntityManager` injected into `@PersistenceContext`-annotated field. See [13.5.2 Implementing DAOs based on plain JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight).

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry - I don't see how this fits in with what I'm asking.